# eclipse fatal error under ubuntu

Tags: java, eclipse, subclipse

causes:
1.connect to a svn resp from eclipse;
2.open a android virtual device

the error log seems complex:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007feaeed0c1c0, pid=29042, tid=140646465390352
#
# JRE version: 6.0
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (19.0-b09 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [ld-linux-x86-64.so.2+0x11c0]
...
Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  org.tigris.subversion.javahl.SVNClient.info2(Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/tigris/subversion/javahl/Revision;Lorg/tigris/subversion/javahl/Revision;I[Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/tigris/subversion/javahl/InfoCallback;)V+0
j  org.tigris.subversion.javahl.SVNClient.info2(Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/tigris/subversion/javahl/Revision;Lorg/tigris/subversion/javahl/Revision;Z)[Lorg/tigris/subversion/javahl/Info2;+23
j  org.tigris.subversion.svnclientadapter.javahl.AbstractJhlClientAdapter.getInfo(Lorg/tigris/subversion/svnclientadapter/SVNUrl;Lorg/tigris/subversion/svnclientadapter/SVNRevision;Lorg/tigris/subversion/svnclientadapter/SVNRevision;)
...
---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------
Current thread (0x00007feadc16f800):  JavaThread "ModalContext" [_thread_in_native, id=29087, stack(0x00007feace8bc000,0x00007feace9bd000)]
siginfo:si_signo=SIGSEGV: si_errno=0, si_code=128 (), si_addr=0x0000000000000000
...
...
uname:Linux 2.6.38.8-621 #2 SMP Wed Sep 14 13:43:05 PDT 2011 x86_64
libc:glibc 2.11.1 NPTL 2.11.1 
rlimit: STACK 8192k, CORE 0k, NPROC 32768, NOFILE 32768, AS infinity
load average:0.07 0.12 0.12
```

Comment: Never had this problem (I use Debian anyway). Which Ubuntu version?

Comment: making sure your Ubuntu's JVM (and other packages) is up-to-date can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

File a bug report with Ubuntu -- a JVM isn't supposed to segv. If you ellided lines from the error log to post it here, be sure to leave those lines *in* when you file a bug report. There isn't enough information in this error log, as posted, to find the bug.

There's a chance that the bug is in some JNI code being executed by your program -- but again, this error log doesn't have the necessary data to discover that.

Comment: +1 If you can reproduce the crash, then send tell them the steps, they will be interested.

Comment: Thanks all,problem solved because my JVM is 32-bit but the eclipse is 64-bit---surely a JVM isn't supposed to segv.

Answer (score 0):

Only java eclipse seems to be tested with is Oracle's implementation. 
Install that (currently it's probably best to use last 1.6.x version) and make sure eclipse uses it (that it's default or specified in eclipse.ini).